# Contract to lie publicly

Tags: contract-law

I asked a question about this earlier but worded it poorly and got downvotes, so I deleted it and gave myself time to  word it better. Please suggest improvements if need be.

Is a contract void if it provides for a party to tell a specified lie, knowingly and publicly, in exchange for a reward...

even if, absent the contract, the lie itself wouldn't be a criminal offence or cause for damages?

EDIT: one of the answerers in the following link basically answered my question in the negative *en passant*, but offered no explanation or justification for that particular point.

[Contracts that require you to lie](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/83828/contracts-that-require-you-to-lie?rq=1)

Comment: Deletion to reask is not how the system is supposed to work.